# Can I use the VS Code API to implement language features in a web extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I generated a VS Code *web* extension, registered the language into the `package.json` file, and put this code snippet into the `extension.ts` file:

```
console.log('activation');
context.subscriptions.push(vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider(selector, {
    provideHover: function (document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.Hover> {
        console.log('hover');
        return new vscode.Hover('test');
    }
}));
```

If I start the extension by pressing the `F5` key (it starts a new VS Code instance to run the extension), it works fine, but if I run the `run-in-browser` npm script it doesn't work. The `activate` function runs in both cases, because I see the text 'activation' in the console, but if I run in the browser I can't see the text 'hover'.

In normal (not web) VS Code extensions I can use both the VS Code API and the Language Server Protocol to implement language features like hover, formatting, go to definition etc. In the [web extensions page](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/web-extensions) they don't mention that I can only use the Language Server Protocol (and not the API) in web extensions, but in the only [web extension sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/lsp-web-extension-sample) where they implement language features, they use the Language Server Protocol.

So, is it possible to use the VS Code API to implement language features in web extensions, or I have to use the Language Server Protocol? If it's possible, why my code doesn't work in the browser but it does in desktop VS Code (using the web environment)?

Comment: you don't return `Hover` instances, an object `{}` is not a `Hover` instance

Comment: I don't think it's a problem, because I have all the `Hover` class's mandatory properties (`contents`), and it works fine if I use the VS Code instance. But just in case, I changed it to this: `return new vscode.Hover('test');`. It still doesn't work. Also it doesn't print 'hover' into the console, which means there is a problem before the return statement.